# Custom dojo widgets not loading on default.htm

Tags: javascript, iis, dojo

I've got a web page (default.htm) that loads some custom dojo widgets.  The widgets load fine when the entire url is typed:

http:/www.eg/default.htm

but when the site is hit as:
    http:/www.eg 
the widgets dont load.

when they load properly (when default.htm is specified) the console message is:
XHR finished loading:

```
GET "http://www.eg/Templates/WatershedMap.htm"
```

when they dont load the console message is:

```
OPTIONS http://templates/WatershedMap.htm net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I'm running iis 7.  Does anyone have an idea of how I might fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that in your dojoConf or data-dojo-conf, you are using `location.pathname`, is that correct? Or perhaps directly in your xhr request where WatershedMap.htm is loaded?

When you view the page with just http;//www.eg/, the `location.pathname` is just a slash "/". If then, for example, xhr tries to do this:

```
xhr(location.pathname + "/Templates/WatershedMap.html")...
```

... then the request will actually go to `//Templates/WatershedMap.html`.

That double slash means "[protocol relative url](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)". The browser will take the same protocol scheme (http/https) as the current page, and append whatever comes after the double slash.

In other words, that will actually try to make a cross domain request to http;//Templates , which triggers a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

However, when your page is loaded with http;//www.eg/foo/, the `location.pathname` will be "/something/something", and the request will go to http;//www.eg/foo/Templates/WatershedMap.htm.

You will have to share some more code if you need help to pinpoint the problem. Look through your code for `location.pathname` and see if you find anything that may be relevant.

**Edit:** based on your comment, your dojoConf has the following:

```
packages: [{
   name: "Templates", 
   location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Templates"
}]
```

The line with replace() in it takes the current page's path (for example /foo/bar.htm), and removes the last slash and everything after it, then appends "/Templates".

It is supposed to ensure that whenever you load something that starts with "Templates" (for example if you do `dojo/text!Templates/Map.htm`, it will look in the same directory on your server as the current page.

However, When you are on http;//www.eg/ , the pathname is simply a slash, and nothing is removed. So you end up with "//Templates". As mentioned earlier, this becomes a protocol relative url, with Templates as the hostname. Definitely not what you want!

On the other hand, when you are on http;//www.eg/default.htm, the pathname is /default.htm, so all of that is stripped away, and you're left with just "/Templates". This *is* what you want!

You could solve it by simply replacing the line with:

```
   location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, "") + "/Templates"
```

Only a single character difference (+ became *)! Now it will remove the single slash if you are viewing http;//www.eg/ as well.

In my opinion though, it's better to use an explicit path. If you know that /Templates will always be http;//www.eg/Templates, you may as well do:

```
   location: "/Templates"
```

Comment: in dojoConfig I'm specifying the package as:
 packages: [
    {name: "Templates", location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Templates"}
    ]   
Thanks

Comment: @pvitt I updated the answer (probably too many details, but hey :P), see if that helps.

Comment: Thank You.  That did the trick -- I'll use the location:"/Templates" on the server